# Cronjob deleted but cron still sends email

Tags: cron

I have in `/etc/crontab` a job defined like this:

`0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * root /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=example.com -update`

I deleted this job but cron sends me still emails every ten minutes.

How can I stop these emails?

My OS is Raspbian 9 Stretch.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just to make sure, did you use "crontab -e" to delete that line or edit some files unbeknownst to cron?

Comment: I added the line in `sudo nano /etc/crontab` then i deleted it out of `sudo nano /etc/crontab`

Comment: @wolf You MUST use `crontab -e` to edit a user cron table or `sudo crontab -e` to edit the root cron table.  Doing anything else will have unknown consequences.

Answer (score 3):

Always use

```
crontab -e
```

to edit the current users crontab entries or

```
sudo crontab -e
```

to create, edit, or delete crontab entries for the user root. Do not edit any files belonging to cron directly. That just will not work.

See bullet 10 [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference):

> User crontab files are stored by the login names in different locations in different Unix and Linux flavors. These files are useful for backing up, viewing and restoring but should be edited only with crontab command by the users.

Comment: In `/etc/crontab` you can run a task with a different user. I'd like to run the job as root. You can define that there. The file looks almost the same as `crontab -e`.

Comment: Use sudo to edit root’s crontab

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed it. I had to delete the file `awstats` in the `/etc/cron.d` directory.